# Sending ctrl-r to ipython running in emacs

Tags: emacs, ipython

I have the following simple script in my ~/.emacs:

```
(defun ipython ()
    (interactive)
    (term "ipython")
```

It works as I'd like it to, except for that when I try to use the history search with ctrl-r, it is interpreted as an emacs command. How do I avoid this for the ipython interpreter?

For bonus points, please tell me how I can make a key press that will make any command following it be interpreted in ipython, not emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wish I had a better answer, but if I do (term "/usr/local/bin/ipython"), and hit Ctrl-R, Emacs does the right thing and lets me incremental search through the command history.  I'm not sure why your Ctrl-R is behaving differently, but I'm on Emacs 24.4.50.1 on OS X.

You can try hitting Ctrl-Q which is supposed to send the next keystroke to the process literally instead of having Emacs interpret it.

Comment: Thanks, will look closer at this after the weekend; unable to reach my work settings from home.

Comment: I'm also on OS X, but for me I had to use the CMD+r to get history searches. This problem seems to be widespread with no definite answers, so accepting your answer, but for other reading this answer: YMMV.